# Getting the wrong featured image on archive page

Tags: shortcode, post-thumbnails, archives

I assigned my posts archive to a site on settings -> reading.
I added a post thumbnail to this site, and i want to show the image with a shortcode i have written in my plugin. The problem is, that the shortcode returns the wrong ID for archive pages (it returns zero). So the first image of the last post is returned as image.
On a normal site the shortcode is working fine, because the ID is returned correctly.

```
function lwb_image_shortcode( $atts ) {
    
    // Attribute für den Shortcode festlegen
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type'      => 'featured',  // Welches Bild, Standard = Haupt Beitragsbild
            'return'    => 'full',      // Rückgabewert - Full = HTML Image Element | URL = Bild URL
            'size'      => 'medium',    // Wordpress Bildgrössen Name  
        ),
        $atts, 'lwb_image'
    );  
    
    if( $atts['return'] == 'full' ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( get_post_thumbnail_id(), $atts['size'], '', '' );
        
    } elseif( $atts['return'] == 'url' ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( get_post_thumbnail_id(), $atts['size'], '', '' );
        
    }
    
    return $image;
}
add_shortcode('lwb_image', 'lwb_image_shortcode');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `WP_Query` object on the blog homepage is the feed of blog posts rather than the page itself, so you'll need to grab the post ID manually and pass it to `get_post_thumbnail_id()`:

```
function lwb_image_shortcode( $atts ) {
    

    // Attribute für den Shortcode festlegen
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'type'      => 'featured',  // Welches Bild, Standard = Haupt Beitragsbild
            'return'    => 'full',      // Rückgabewert - Full = HTML Image Element | URL = Bild URL
            'size'      => 'medium',    // Wordpress Bildgrössen Name  
        ),
        $atts, 'lwb_image'
    );  
    if( is_home() ) {
        $id = get_post_thumbnail_id( (int) get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
    }
    else {
        $id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    }
    if( $atts['return'] == 'full' ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $atts['size'], '', '' );
        
    } elseif( $atts['return'] == 'url' ) {
        $image = wp_get_attachment_image_url( $id, $atts['size'], '', '' );
        
    }
    
    return $image;
}
add_shortcode('lwb_image', 'lwb_image_shortcode');
```

Comment: thank you, that did the job...